# PHP application with visible/hidden parts before and after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to create a PHP application, where there is a button "Select Drivers", which shows a form if clicked, where there is a Dropdown list of driver groups. After selection of the group in Dropdown list, the form details should be processed in PHP and the list of drivers shown.

I don't have much knowledge of JavaScript and AJAX, so the way I implemented the application is that the form is submitted after the selection of the group in Dropdown list and the list of drivers are not shown, because the page is reloaded after submission and the HTML Div part with Group and Driver details become hidden again. So, in order to see this list, I have to press the button "Select Drivers" again.

My Javascript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openDrivers(){                        
                    if (document.getElementById('driverGroups').style.display== 'none')                        
                        document.getElementById('driverGroups').style.display='block';              
                    else if (document.getElementById('driverGroups').style.display== 'block')
                document.getElementById('driverGroups').style.display= 'none';
        };
</script>
```

And this part is HTML + PHP:

```
<form  action="ragSelect.php" method="post" id="form">
<!-- DRIVERS SELECTION WINDOW -->
<input type="button"  onclick="openDrivers();" id="driversButton" value="Select Drivers" /> <br>
<div id = "driverGroups" style="display: none" >
    <br>
    <select id ="selectGroup" name="taskOption"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option selected = "selected"> Select Group </option>
    <?php 
        $drGroup = getAvailableDriverGroups(); 
        for ($x = 0; $x<count($drGroup);$x++)  
        echo '<option value="'.$drGroup[$x]['name'].'">'.$drGroup[$x]['name'].'</option>';
    ?>
    </select> 

        <div id = "groupDrivers" >
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['taskOption']))
                    {
                        $selectOption = $_POST['taskOption'];
                        echo $selectOption."<br>";
                        $grID = groupID($selectOption, $drGroup);
                        $groupName =$selectOption;
                        $driverGroup = getDriverGroup($wialon_api, $grID,$groupName);
                        for ($x=0;$x<count($driverGroup[$x]);$x++)
                            echo 'ID: '.($driverGroup[$x])."<br>";
                    }



            ?>  
        </div>


</div>
```

Can anyone advice something with that issue? Thank you

Comment: You could spend a lot of effort and eventually get it to work. You'd be better off though if you do it it properly, i.e. with AJAX and avoiding mixing PHP and HTML.

Comment: Okay, it seems the best solution is AJAX. I have implemented it with AJAX now. Thanks